# How I could host the html documentation of my API to be browseable online in GitHub?

Tags: api, hosting, html, github-pages

I wonder if exists a **free** online service for developers where to host the contents of a library's API documentation, I mean the **index.html** and all the files that composes a html documentation.

This is the documentation that I will host with the intention to be browseable online:

- http://www.mediafire.com/download/244x2i13vtp6j1d/Web.rar

My current projects are hosted in **GitHub**, and one person told me that I could host the html documentation using **GitHub-Pages**, but I think can't, I already created a page using the GitHub-Pages for my repository but seems only can be a single and simple html page with no chance to do/upload what I require, anyways, I'm not totally sure.

If with github-pages isn't possible to do, then I'll look for a free service alternative that offers a guided way to this, instead of registering in a free web-hosting to create your domain then access the admin panel then upload the files then blah blah blah...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who says you can't have more than one page on your GHub Pages? Make a new file, for instance called `api.html` or `api.txt` or whatever you want. On this new page, you can include a download link for your rar. Add a `<a href="mypage.html">` in your index.html. Style it however you want, and people can go through.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The contents of the compressed file that I shared are more than 7.000 files, with github pages the only way to go is creating manually each page?, how I could do what I need?.

Comment: Edited. Does this explain?

Comment: No, the intention is not to offer a download of a compressed file (which I could upload in the github repository), is to offer a browseable mechanism for the index.html of the documentation and the files that composses it.